# How do I apply these fuzzy logic operations to my custom boolean class?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, boolean-logic, fuzzy-logic

## Context

I have a custom fuzzy boolean class, called **`F_Bool`**, that is represented by a value between zero and one, inclusive.

*(See code sample below)*

### What I know

In most fuzzy logic applications, the logical operators `|`, `&`, and `!` are pretty straightforward. For `a|b => Max(a.val, b.val)`, `a&b => Min(a.val, b.val)`, and `!a => 1 - a.val`.

For operators such as `+` and `-`, the task becomes a little trickier. For `a+b` (after some trial and error) I've found that I can take the average `a+b => (a.val + b.val) / 2`. For `a-b` (after even more trial and error) I found that `a-b => a+!b => (1 + a.val - b.val) / 2`.

### Where I'm stuck

I am aware that my "solution" for addition and subtraction isn't ideal because it doesn't allow for `a+b+c` (which should be the average of the three values), but I can figure that out later.

I am mainly wondering how I can implement the `*` and `/` operators for my class in a similar manner, and what such an operation might imply in terms of fuzzy boolean logic.

## Question

If "adding" two fuzzy booleans together is equivalent to averaging their values, **what does it mean to multiply/divide two fuzzy booleans together?** Is there even a logical equivalent?

Below is a code sample of what I'm talking about.

#### Code Sample

```
// Represents a boolean using a decimal
public class F_Bool
{
    // The fuzzified value
    public decimal val;

    // The defuzzified value
    public bool boolVal {
        get => val >= 0.5M;
        set => val = value ? 1M : 0M;
    }

    // Constructors
    public F_Bool (decimal value) =>
        val = value;
    public F_Bool (bool value) =>
        boolVal = value;

    // AND: takes the Min value of {a, b}
    public static F_Bool operator &(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) =>
        new F_Bool( Math.Min(a.val, b.val) );

    //  OR: takes the Max value of {a, b}
    public static F_Bool operator |(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) =>
        new F_Bool( Math.Max(a.val, b.val) );

    // NOT: Inverts the value of f
    public static F_Bool operator !(F_Bool f) =>
        new F_Bool (1 - f.val);

    // SUM: Returns the average of {a, b}
    public static F_Bool operator +(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) =>
        new F_Bool ( (a.val+ b.val) / 2 );

    // DIF: Returns the average of {a, NOT b}
    public static F_Bool operator -(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) =>
        a + !b;

    /* Trivially Implemented */

    // PRODUCT: ??? of {?a?, ?b?}
    /* I presume I will return a*b; */
    public static F_Bool operator *(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) {
        if(a.val== 0 | b.val== 0) return new F_Bool(0);
        else if(b.val== 1) return a;
        else if(a.val== 1) return b;
        else // return a * b; // correct?
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    // QUOTIENT: ??? of {?a?, ?b?}
    /* I have no idea, but a/b is wrong. *
     *   - Would Min(a,b)/Max(a,b) work? *
     *   - What about (a-b)/(a+b)?       */
    public static F_Bool operator /(F_Bool a, F_Bool b) {
        if(b.val == 0) throw new DivideByZeroException();
        else if(a.val == 0) return 0;
        else if(b.val == 1) return a;
        else  // return a/b; // incorrect! (produces values > 1)
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

###### Any help is greatly appreciated

## Thank you!

Comment: If the arithmetic mean is the method used when adding two `F_Bool`s together, could one of the other Pythagorean means be used to multiply or divide them?

Comment: Am I even thinking about addition correctly? I understand it was a rather arbitrary choice, but it seems to make sense to me. My reasoning is that, in the case that 1 (true) is added to 0 (false), the result should be halfway in between, or 1+0 => 0.5. Does this logic hold?